Laravel relations not returning nested relations
I have an Order model in my Laravel application, the Order model can have many Order items.
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}

My Order Item model relates to my Embroidery model, an Order Item can have 1 Embroidery model,
public function embroidery()
{
    $this->hasOne(Embroidery::class);
}

The Order Item model also has a relation with the Pattern model,
public function pattern()
{
    $this->hasOne(Pattern::class);
}

The problem I am having is,
Order::with('items')->first();

Works absolutely fine, and I can see the Orders related Items, however, if I do
Order::with('items.embroidery')->first()

I get the following error, and I cannot figure out why?

Error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null


Laravel expects each relationship method to return an instance of a relationship.
Missing return ??
public function embroidery()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Embroidery::class);
}

public function pattern()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Pattern::class);
}

After that you can use
Order::with('items.embroidery')->first()

Laravel Docs

also specifying the return type of the method public function pattern(): HasOne makes this kind of mistake much less common and the error message much more meaningful
